# Expression Engine - Import Member Data, create XML file Parse Error

Tags: expressionengine

I am trying to use the the Utilities > Member Import Utility to create an XML file that I can then use to import member data.

I have about seventy members to import. I was able to work through the mapping with what appeared to be a good match, but when I click the button, I get the following error:

> Line does not match structure

I am using a .csv file to bring the data and I have selected comma as the deliminator. I can map the fields but when I click Create XML I get the Parse error.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your CSV file use any enclosing characters (such as double quotes) to encapsulate the data? If it doesn't, you might try wrapping each item with quotes to help the import utility parse any special characters you may have in your member data. Then be sure to select the appropriate option during the Text to XML conversion process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I appears to automatically understand that it is relative. When I simply put the name of the file in it went in with error.

So the correct path is: customer.txt

However, because the username is a number and not alpha numeric it cannot be imported.